# How to fetch recent emails using JavaMail API in Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to fetch emails using the JavaMail API in Java. I want to fetch mails between particular dates, but the problem is that I am not able to fetch current date emails for example: If I have to fetch mails from 16/11/18 to 17/11/18 or have to fetch only the 17/11/18, I am not able to fetch those emails, that is, I am unable fetch the recent emails. Below is my code.

```
SimpleDateFormat somePastDate = new SimpleDateFormat( "EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
String dt="Thu Nov 15 01:53:10 IST 2018";

java.util.Date pastDate = somePastDate.parse(dt);
System.out.println("the past Date is "+pastDate);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",
        Locale.ENGLISH);
String futureDate = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
java.util.Date somefutureDate=formatter.parse(futureDate);
System.out.println("the future date is "+somefutureDate);

SearchTerm olderThan=new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.LT,somefutureDate);
SearchTerm newerThann=new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.GT,pastDate);
SearchTerm andTerm=new AndTerm(olderThan,newerThann);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaMail reading recent unread mails using IMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28689099/javamail-reading-recent-unread-mails-using-imap)

Answer (score 0):

Please try using

`SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();`

`format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");`

Define two dates objects and use this format examples show above.
than do the rest which you have made already in your code..

Good Luck
Yaniv