# javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to read unread emails using Java program.I am using below mentioned java code which I took from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_fetching_emails.htm. I have turned on less secure apps access in gmail settings. Please help me to resolve the issue.

```
public class FetchingEmail {

   public static void fetch(String pop3Host, String storeType, String user,
      String password) {
      try {
         Properties properties = new Properties();
         properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
         properties.put("mail.pop3.host", pop3Host);
         properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
         properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "*");
         Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
         Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");

         store.connect(pop3Host, user, password);
         Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
         emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
          System.in));
         Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
         System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

         for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            Message message = messages[i];
            System.out.println("---------------------------------");
            writePart(message);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if ("YES".equals(line)) {
               message.writeTo(System.out);
            } else if ("QUIT".equals(line)) {
               break;
            }
         }
         emailFolder.close(false);
         store.close();

      } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (MessagingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      String host = "pop.gmail.com";// change accordingly
      String mailStoreType = "pop3";
      String username = "abc@gmail.com";
         //"abc@gmail.com";// change accordingly
      String password = "abc";// change accordingly
      fetch(host, mailStoreType, username, password);

   }
   public static void writePart(Part p) throws Exception {
      if (p instanceof Message)
         writeEnvelope((Message) p);

      System.out.println("----------------------------");
      System.out.println("CONTENT-TYPE: " + p.getContentType());
      if (p.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
         System.out.println("This is plain text");
         System.out.println("---------------------------");
         System.out.println((String) p.getContent());
      }
      else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
         System.out.println("This is a Multipart");
         System.out.println("---------------------------");
         Multipart mp = (Multipart) p.getContent();
         int count = mp.getCount();
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            writePart(mp.getBodyPart(i));
      }
      else if (p.isMimeType("message/rfc822")) {
         System.out.println("This is a Nested Message");
         System.out.println("---------------------------");
         writePart((Part) p.getContent());
      }       
      else if (p.getContentType().contains("image/")) {
         System.out.println("content type" + p.getContentType());
         File f = new File("image" + new Date().getTime() + ".jpg");
         DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(
            new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f)));
            com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream test = 
                 (com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream) p
                  .getContent();
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
         int bytesRead;
         while ((bytesRead = test.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
         }
      } 
      else {
         Object o = p.getContent();
         if (o instanceof String) {
            System.out.println("This is a string");
            System.out.println("---------------------------");
            System.out.println((String) o);
         } 
         else if (o instanceof InputStream) {
            System.out.println("This is just an input stream");
            System.out.println("---------------------------");
            InputStream is = (InputStream) o;
            is = (InputStream) o;
            int c;
            while ((c = is.read()) != -1)
               System.out.write(c);
         } 
         else {
            System.out.println("This is an unknown type");
            System.out.println("---------------------------");
            System.out.println(o.toString());
         }
      }

   }
   public static void writeEnvelope(Message m) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("This is the message envelope");
      System.out.println("---------------------------");
      Address[] a;
      if ((a = m.getFrom()) != null) {
         for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
         System.out.println("FROM: " + a[j].toString());
      }
      if ((a = m.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO)) != null) {
         for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
         System.out.println("TO: " + a[j].toString());
      }
      if (m.getSubject() != null)
         System.out.println("SUBJECT: " + m.getSubject());

   }

}
```

But I am getting below exception. I have posted stack trace.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:213)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at com.util.FetchingEmail.fetch(FetchingEmail.java:62)
    at com.util.FetchingEmail.main(FetchingEmail.java:110)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1964)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:328)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:322)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1614)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:987)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:598)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:372)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:112)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.getPort(POP3Store.java:265)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:207)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1596)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Java program stopped sending emails using my gmail Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098281/my-java-program-stopped-sending-emails-using-my-gmail-account)

Comment: @Sharon, Thanks for your comment. It resolved my problem. But I am getting all email. I need to get only unread emails.

Comment: try googling, its faster than me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28689099/javamail-reading-recent-unread-mails-using-imap