# How to access a mail account via IMAP with java using my Active Directory user and password?

Tags: java, email, active-directory, jakarta-mail, imap

I have a requirement in which I need to develop in java a way to access an exchange email (Outlook) through IMAP using the email account, a network username and its network password as authentication.

As an example I have the following:

Email account: hello@company123.com

Network user: User123

Network password: Pass123

So the idea is setting a call kinda connectIMAP("hello@company123.com","User123","Pass123") for reading hello@company123.com emails

I checked the following code that I took from another question ( [JavaMail reading recent unread mails using IMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28689099/javamail-reading-recent-unread-mails-using-imap) ) but it only shows how to access a gmail account using the email as user.

```
public class GmailFetch {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties( ));
        Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect("imap.googlemail.com", 993, "username@gmail.com", "password");
        Folder inbox = store.getFolder( "INBOX" );
        inbox.open( Folder.READ_ONLY );

        // Fetch unseen messages from inbox folder
        Message[] messages = inbox.search(
            new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));

        // Sort messages from recent to oldest
        Arrays.sort( messages, ( m1, m2 ) -> {
          try {
            return m2.getSentDate().compareTo( m1.getSentDate() );
          } catch ( MessagingException e ) {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
          }
        } );

        for ( Message message : messages ) {
            System.out.println( 
              "sendDate: " + message.getSentDate()
              + " subject:" + message.getSubject() );
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: You want to do something and you found some code to do it. What's the problem?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `store.connect` line to your server info?

Comment: @arnt store.connect only let you configure the email account as user and the email password as password, and I need to do it with network credentials.  Consider that a network user can have many linked email accounts, so I need a method (or another way) to authenticate with the email account, network user and network password.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Yes.  i already tried doing: store.connect("imap.myserver.com", 993, "hello@company123.com", "Pass123"); , store.connect("imap.myserver.com", 993, "User123", "Pass123"); and store.connect("imap.myserver.com", 993, "hello@company123.com", "User123","Pass123"); and none of those work

Comment: It sounds as if what you want is to configure the IMAP server to allow access using those passwords. Which is perfectly possible, but is not a programming question and therefore off-topic. If the server is correctly configured and your question is how to use it, [one of these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javamail+single-sign-on) may help.

Comment: What version of JavaMail are you using?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show? Does this [JavaMail FAQ entry](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#Exchange-login) help?